# creating html page from xml file

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets, xml-parsing

I reading xml document which consists of html elements. Now I need to fetch the data from that xml file and construct a HTML and display it using servlets or javascript. How do I do that, please suggest any method or tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform your XML document into an [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML) page.

There's an open-source XSLT servlet available [here](http://flavio.tordini.org/xslt-servlet).

Answer (score 4):

You should use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) for [this task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Application). Start with a [basic tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xslttutorial.php).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in java there are 3 apis to read and parse xml data:
* dom: reads whole file at once and lets you access data with random access. high memory usage.
* sax: stream-reads file and lets you react on events. Low memory usage, more complicated than dom.
* stax: similar to sax, but more modern interface, event based. also low memory usage.

How to present the information from the HTML file cannot be explained in a single answer here, hundreds of books were written about that.
Among the possibilities are:
You can do HTML creation yourself (prgramatically in java) or you could use JSP, JSF, Ruby on Rails, XSLT, Velocity, GWT, Tapestry, Wicket, JBoss Seam, WebWork, just to name a few.

Comment: thats awesome @Ron, thanks a lot for sharing valuable information